# UAC management for an app build with electron-packager

Tags: node.js, electron, elevated-privileges

I used the winreg npm package for my app and I need elevated privileges for the uses I have.

I would like to associate a manifest file with an app build with electron (atom-shell) and packaged on windows with electron-packager but I can not find any way to do it easily.

An old app of mine was made with cx_freeze and it sufficed to put the file with the name app.exe.manifest in the same directory.

I can't understand why it doesn't work this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

So first thing to know is that an external manifest won't count if an embedded manifest is already present. (see answer to https://superuser.com/questions/905103/what-does-it-mean-to-enable-windows-to-prioritise-external-manifests)

And it turns out that the electron.exe has already a manifest embedded 
and the package done with electron-package is mostly a rename of the 
electron executable.

So in order to embed a news manifest with the right privileges needed, I took the manifest in the electron repo (see https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/atom/browser/resources/win/atom.manifest), edited the security section and used the mt.exe tool to add the new manifest (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And tadaa !